# Getting link to my app on play.google before posting my app

Tags: android, facebook, hyperlink, google-play

I want to share link to my app(link on play.google) using facebook api. But I have to have it before posting app on market to put it in my code. Are there any other solutions except updating my app right after posting?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use this

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<your package name>
```

and you can get package name by this way.

```
   String packageName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
```

currently it will not show any app but after publishing it automatically redirect in your app page.

Comment: How do I find "Your package name" , is that just the app name?  with spaces (mine is 3 words)