# Where is link of newly published android application?

Tags: android

I just published my first application on android market. I know it will takes 48 hr but When,Where and how can i get Link of my application. So I can share it with my friends ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a link that doesn't exist yet.  When it does, this question will become obsolete, as the answer should be apparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App link remains as

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=yourPackageName
```

so append your  app package name as id parameter.

see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11862441/942224

Answer (score 1):

You can either use ...

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<your.package.name>
```

... for HTML links in the web or ...

```
market://details?id=<your.package.name>
```

... for links that are interpreted by Android. Last one opens the Google Play app.